# why this strange behavior of OpenJpa?

Tags: java, postgresql, openjpa

why do this query works directly on postgres database:

```
select m from medicine_case m WHERE m.id IN (select m.id  FROM medicine_case m  LEFT OUTER JOIN patient ON m.patient=patient.id  ORDER BY patient.surname ASC )
```

AND in OpenJpa with the exact corresponding typed query:

```
String sql = " select m from medicine_case m WHERE m.id IN (select m.id  FROM medicine_case m  LEFT OUTER JOIN "
                + "patient ON m.patient=patient.id  ORDER BY patient.surname ASC )";
        TypedQuery<MedicineCase> query = persistenceClient.createQueryMC(sql);
        setParameter(query);
        query.setFirstResult(first);
        query.setMaxResults(count);
```

gives me:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered "m . id IN ( select m . id FROM medicine_case m LEFT OUTER JOIN patient ON" at character 37, but expected: ["(", ")", "*",.... etc etc
```

why????? it's so strange and makes me crazy!

the code that creates the query from entity manager:

```
return entityManager.createQuery(sql, MedicineCase.class);
```

and the code that executes it:

`return query.getResultList().iterator();`

Comment: Are you sure the SQL works in postgres? Is there a column called `m`?

Comment: Between the line where you initialize `String sql` and `TypedQuery<MedicineCase> query`, you should check the value of `sql` via breakpoints or outputting `sql`.

Comment: yes it works, I executed it in postgres console... and there isn't a column called m, but this syntax means that you want as result an object m representing table and  not only a list of columns

Comment: What's the code of `persistenceClient.createQueryMC(sql)`?

Comment: I debugged in fact and I get correctly by log : `creating query for medicine case from sql:  select m from medicine_case m WHERE m.id IN (select m.id  FROM medicine_case m  LEFT OUTER JOIN patient ON m.patient=patient.id  ORDER BY patient.surname ASC )`

Comment: I debugged, createQuery(sql, MedicineCase.class) fails... I don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing SQL (which is what PostgreSQL expects) and HQL (which is what `EntityManager.createQuery()` expects).

Those are two different languages. SQL works with tables and columns, whereas JPQL works with JPA entities, fields/properties and associations, and is translated by your JPA implementation into SQL.

If you want to execute SQL, you must use `EntityManager.createNativeQuery()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a newbie of jpa and I don't know this difference... unfortunately I cannot use createNativeQuery because I need to get a complex object and simple query isn't powerful enough to give me a comlete MedicineCase object (which contains relations with other objects), how can I implement IN-clause in JPQL? Can you help me?

Comment: If you don't even know that JPQL exists, read a tutorial or book first, then try something, before asking for help. That said, your query is too complex. Just running the inner query would lead to the same result.

Comment: Thank you very much, I asked for help only for my work time restrictions. Could you suggest me a good tutorial on internet?

Comment: I learnt mainly by reading the Hibernate reference documentation, and the JPA specification. Not sure this is the fastest way to learn though.

Comment: found solution and learnt how to make it! thanks for your starboard

Answer (score 0):

in jpql it becomes a bit different:

```
String sql = "select m from " + MedicineCase.class.getSimpleName() + " m WHERE m.id IN :mcList";
TypedQuery<MedicineCase> query = persistenceClient.createQueryMC(sql);
        query.setParameter("mcList", persistenceClient.executeQueryMCId(persistenceClient.createQueryMCId(createSql()
                + addOrders())));
        setParameter(query);
        query.setFirstResult(first);
        query.setMaxResults(count);
        return persistenceClient.executeQueryMC(query);
```

where createSql returns:

```
sql.append("select m.id ").append(" FROM ").append(MedicineCase.class.getSimpleName()).append(" m");
```

and addOrders:

```
" LEFT OUTER JOIN m.patient p ORDER BY p.surname ASC
```